# Python: two questions about a "numpy.ndarray"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created a numpy.ndarray with value

import numpy as np
from numpy import nonzero

```
data = np.zeros((5, 5))
data
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

i wish to change some values with 1

```
data[0,0] = 1
data[4,4] = 1

data
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

if i change 0 with 5 using negative values i have

```
data[-5,-5] = 5
data[-4,-4] = 5

>>> data
array([[ 5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

1- I don't understand why i have not an error message as

```
>>> data[10,10] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index (10) out of range (0<=index<5) in dimension 0
```

2- it's not clear why with data[-5,-5] = 5 and data[-4,-4] = 5 the value 5 is inserted in position 0,0 and 1,1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing):

> Negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end of the array

This is the standard Python indexing behavior (used in Python lists, etc.).

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn, I skipped that sentence. Thanks again